# Portable linux with disk-encryption: Which type of storage is better? SD-CARD or USB-STICK

Tags: encryption, usb-drive, live-usb, storage, sd-card

So, as stated above, I mainly address some people, which may have made some experience with a portable os and various storage-types.
As we know, the good old HDD are the most durable types of disks.

Then there are ssd's.

And somewhere after them, we have the memory-sticks, usb-sticks, sd-cards, etc.

Currently I have a linux distro installed on my usb-drive, with full disc encryption. It runs smooth, very fast ( though being an USB-2 port )  and I really enjoy this, i enjoy this that much, that i almost never plug out this already small usb-stick. Ok, it get's a bit warm, but I do not care.

Two weeks ago I bought myself a SD-Card. I plugged it into my lap and I am even more satisfied, because it has no edge being outside at all, it is completely inside the slot. This small advantage is already enough for me to ask:

Should I consider to transfer my os from my USB to the sd-card ?
Both have the same size, vendor, and appereantly the same speed-specifications.

Will my usb-drive live longer then the sd-card? Will the sd-card also get warm, like the USB-drive does ? Is the usb-drive more designed to work with many quick read/write-accesses or the sd-card ?

Is there a general recommendation at all ?

Comment: I'd immediately object to "*the good old HDD are the most durable types of disks*"... I've read some CDs & DVDs are supposed to be readable for almost a century

Comment: You are a specialist. I talk about read-write.

Comment: DVD-RW's can be rated for 1000+ writes, just like many flash memory based devices (USBs/SDs), and I haven't read that DVD-RW's will last a century, but decades seems easily achievable

Comment: Good to know, but I never read about DVD-RW's being able to last, let's say, 5 years, if being used for an os, like HDD's are usually.

Comment: Related: [This fellow has some experience with linux installs to SD cards](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136273/37589) (Spoiler: Most fail around 1yr, no market benchmark, "impossible to know the number of writes per memory block, and the technology used in the SDCard")

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your exact USB & SD cards, it's impossible to tell which will "live longer", there are a mind-bogging number of different USB & SD cards, of wildly differing qualities. The manufacturer's warranties may give you some idea of how long they're expected to last, and maybe you're lucky and someone somewhere has done some stress-testing.

And I'm sure they'll both "get warm" but whether that's a problem I couldn't say. If it's not burning your finger or too hot to touch, it's probably relatively normal.

---

HP has some fairly extensive information in a technical white paper on [SD boot: using Secure Digital (SD) card technology for booting HP ProLiant servers](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA4-9872ENW.pdf)

For deploying an OS to an SD card, HP recommends using their [HP 32GB SDHC Enterprise Mainstream Flash Media Kit (Part Number 700136-B21)](http://www8.hp.com/lamerica_nsc_carib/en/products/oas/product-detail.html?oid=5360693) which may cost $100 to $300 US, that advertises:

- Higher write cycles (up to 100,000 write cycles or 10 times greater than consumer products)
- Static and dynamic wear leveling
- Error Correcting Code capability (40bits/1K)
- Data Retention of 1 year at the life end of the flash

HP notes:

> The HP SD and microSD Enterprise Mainstream Flash Media cards are the only SD cards supported by Intelligent 
>   Provisioning. All other SD cards will result in an error message.

And also:

> Due to specific blocking and performance considerations, microSD solutions will actually wear slower than SD solutions

---

Some anecdotal evidence, I tried doing a full Linux install (Ubuntu-based) onto a 32GB Lexar USB that looked just like this one: [image] It did *not* go well, took nearly an hour installing, booted once extremely slowly, then crashed permanently with massive filesystem errors.

I also use the same Lexar USB's for booting live ISO's, mainly read-only but with data storage partitions, works great.

---

More Info:

- [Maximum, demonstrated SD card durability](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/maximum-demonstrated-sd-card-durability) on raspberripi.stackexchange.com
- [How can I extend the life of my SD card?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/169/how-can-i-extend-the-life-of-my-sd-card) on raspberripi.stackexchange.com
- [How to Damage a FLASH Storage Device (And by implication, how not to damage them)](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/How_to_Damage_a_FLASH_Storage_Device)
- [On MicroSD Problems](http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?page_id=1022) - Very interesting article about questionable MicroSD cards possibly made by the “ghost shift”

  - Follow-up: [On Hacking MicroSD Cards](http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?page_id=3592) - Had no idea they were so complicated & "riddled with defects," apparently it's *cheaper* to add an "8051 or ARM CPU" and error-correct & manage bad blocks ($0.15-$0.30) than it is to "thoroughly test and characterize each flash memory chip."

Comment: Look, I also had these boot/fs problems with a golden, small SANDISK USB. Now I have a sandisk usb-drive,  almost the size of a wireless mouse usb-dongle. This one never crashed, never failed to boot ( as the golden did every 3rd time ) and is a lot faster. Perhaps I can post the entire specifications of sd-card and usb-stick in order to help others, to help me.

Comment: For now I've gone with just booting live ISO's from USB/SD, and only copy a few files & programs over from a data partition. Makes virtually no writes to the media unless I want to explicitly save something, and if there's enough ram it copies the entire filesystem to ram, reads a few gigs a second, and also very secure - the core OS is read-only.